# issue in installing DSS feature on wso2 ESB 5.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

For a new project I'd like to setup the new ESB 5.0 adding the dss feature as well. I was about to do it from the wilkes repository (http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/), but during installation it shows following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency. Software being installed: Data Service Hosting Feature 4.3.4 
(org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.feature.group 4.3.4) Software currently installed: WSO2 Carbon - Transaction Manager Feature 4.5.4 
(org.wso2.carbon.transaction.manager.feature.group 4.5.4) Only one of the following can be installed at once: WSO2 Carbon - Transaction Manager Feature 4.4.7 (org.wso2.carbon.transaction.manager.feature.jar 4.4.7) WSO2 Carbon -
 Transaction Manager Feature 4.5.4 (org.wso2.carbon.transaction.manager.feature.jar 4.5.4) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Data Service Hosting Feature 4.3.4 (org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.feature.group 4.3.4) To: org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.server.feature.group [4.3.4] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: Data Service Hosting Feature 4.3.4 (org.wso2.carbon.dataservices.server.feature.group 4.3.4) To: org.wso2.carbon.transaction.manager.feature.group [4.4.0,4.5.0) Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Transaction Manager Feature 4.4.7 (org.wso2.carbon.transaction.manager.feature.group 4.4.7) To: org.wso2.carbon.transaction.manager.feature.jar [4.4.7] Cannot satisfy dependency: From: WSO2 Carbon - Transaction Manager Feature 4.5.4 (org.wso2.carbon.transaction.manager.feature.group 4.5.4) To: org.wso2.carbon.transaction.manager.feature.jar [4.5.4]
```

How can this be solved? the same procedure using ESB 4.9.0 works as expected. Is it something that still to be updated in the new ESB 5.0?

In that case what are the alternatives you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug. I have raised a Jira (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/DS-1249) to track this. This will be fixed in the next release.

Thanks.